# Codeigniter/MYSQL to group cities under each and every state

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have 2 separate tables states and cities. 
I'll need an SQL (Mysql) statement or PHP query to get output data in the following format. (Basically grouping the cities under their respective states).

Output example I'll need (JSON)

```
"Andaman and nicobar" : ['Port Blair', 'Adilabad'],
"Tamilnadu" : ['Chennai', 'Coimbatore'],
"Maharastra" : ['Mumbai', 'Lonavala', 'Pune'],
```

I have the database tables as below.

[image: States Table]

[image]

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: Is that really necessary for this question? It's **5.5.61**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `left join` your states table with cities table in sql and then loop through its result in php and make your desired output. Below I used plain php (assumed a connection already implemented by `$conn`) to work with database. You should implement your own if you're using any framework.

```
$sql = 'SELECT st.state_name, ct.city_name FROM states st LEFT JOIN cities ct on st.state_number=ct.state_number';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$statesWithCities = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $statesWithCities[$row['state_name']][] = $row['city_name'];
}

$jsonOutput = json_encode($statesWithCities);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another version of the accepted answer using CodeIgniter database functions. It also uses a RIGHT join which removes states without any associated cities from the result set.

```
$results = $this->db
           ->query('SELECT state_name, cities.city_name FROM `states` 
                    RIGHT JOIN cities ON state_number=cities.state_number')
           ->result();

$data = [];
foreach ($results as $city)
{
    $data[$city->state_name][] = $city->city_name;
}

$out = json_encode($data);
```